# Java main class not found after renaming

Tags: java, eclipse

After refactor->renaming my main class (which contains the main-Method) eclipse doesn't detect it and I can't run this class (because the list near the green run button doesn't show my class).

I tried *Project -> clean...*, but this didn't change anything.

What is wrong here? Can there be such a big error in eclipse?

Comment: Often I tend to re-import the project into Eclipse which fixes issues like this; have you tried doing that?

Comment: Try to use "run configurations" option and set the name of the main class by the new name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to "Run Configurations...", select your old working configuration, then change the name of the main class to execute.

Or simply right-click on your main class, and select "Run as..."-->"Java application", which will create a new run configuration .